# how to pass request body in post api call java

Tags: java, rest, httpsurlconnection

I am trying to pass Request body while making a Rest Api call (POST). using the following code:

```
String urlString ="url-string-of-api-call";
String body = "{\"type\":\"dog\",\"price\":249.99}";
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
OutputStream writer = conn.getOutputStream();
writer.write(body.getBytes());
writer.flush();
writer.close();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
String output;
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

---

the output is:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "key": "Pet2.type",
      "message": "Missing required field"
    },
    {
      "key": "Pet2.price",
      "message": "Missing required field"
    }
  ]
}
```

which means "type" and "price" is not getting passed as part of the request body

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [mcve]. 'It doesn't seem to be working' is not a question others can easily help you with since it's completely unclear what is going wrong and what it is you are actually asking about.

Comment: The body being passed to the API is null

Comment: Please read the docs above and edit the question accordingly instead of commenting. Your comment doesn't make things any clearer.